# Compare column td values

Tags: jquery

I wanted to compare column td values. When I select a value from row 2 it will determine if its higher or lower on row 1.

```
 $(".field").change(function() {
   var firstDropVal = $(this).val();
   //alert(firstDropVal);
   var column_num = parseInt($(this).index());
   var row_num = parseInt( $(this).parent().index() )+1; 

   //alert("Row_num =" + row_num + "  ,  Column_num ="+ column_num );

   alert($('table tr:eq(0) td:eq('+column_num+')').text());

 });
```

I was able to retrieve the value of the first row, but I'm stuck on getting "3" only.

[image]

here is my [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/rdanalasa/p8de62v7/)

Comment: You want to compare firstDropVal to "3"?

Answer (score 0):

I added some attributes in the `<td>` and `<select>` tags to identify them and did a search based on those attributes, using jQuery, to then compare their respective values.

You can check my version on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p8de62v7/12/).

Comment: I've updated my latest fiddle I think I'm getting close.

Comment: Updated my fiddle based on your idea.

Comment: Yep I tried it try changing the value of first row not just "3".  It's just fixed on getting value of the other column.

Comment: I've found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed my own problem by using jquery `eq` and `index`

```
   $(".number_circles_input").change(function() {

   var pred = $(this).val();
   var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
   var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());

   var par = $('table tr:eq(0) td:eq(' + row + ')').text();

   var score = par - pred;

   alert(score);

   //$('table tr:eq(0) td:eq('+row+')').css("background-color",'black');

 });
```